# Showing that $(Im \alpha ')^{o} \subseteq \theta (ker \alpha)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation $\alpha: V \to V$ and the induced dual transformation $\alpha' :V^* \to V^*$. I also have an isomorphism:

$$\theta: V \to (V^*)^*$$

where

$$\theta(v) = E_v$$

And $E_v$ is the map $E_v: V^* \to V$ given by $E_v(f) = f(v)$

I'm trying to show:

$(Im \alpha ')^{o} \subseteq \theta (ker \alpha)$

So I take an element in the left hand side, this element lives in $V^{**}$ so I can write it as $\theta (v)$ for some $v \in V$ and then I know that: $\theta (v) (g(\alpha))$ is the zero map (in $V^{**}$). Now I want to show that $v$ must be in the kernel of $\alpha$ but I am having difficulty.

Somehow I want to look at the map $\alpha$ in $V^{**}$ under $\theta$ but am not quite sure how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: I think $\;V^*\;$ is more common for the dual space.

Comment: Oh okay, I will change it, just my lecture notes using $V'$

Comment: It's not uncommon to let $V^\ast$ denote the space of all linear functionals on $V$, and $V'$ the space of continuous linear functionals. Or the other way round. There are a lot of different conventions.

Comment: Is $\theta$ the natural map $\theta(v) \colon f \mapsto f(v)$?

Comment: So $\theta$ takes vectors and sends them to their evaluation map

Comment: @DanielFischer I have added some more detail to the post about the nature of $\theta$

Comment: You meant you take an element of the _left_ hand side. And "$\theta(v)(g(\alpha))$" is not right. It's $\theta(v)(\alpha'(g))$, which one can write as $\theta(v)(g\circ\alpha)$ if desired. Use the definition of $\theta$ to rewrite that expression. You should reach $\alpha(v) = 0$ soon after.

Comment: Oh yes, thats really stupid that I didn't spot that. It would have helped to write a clear definition of $\theta$ sooner - I think exam stress is actually making me worse! Thanks for your help